# changing the class of a div in a loop dependant on variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have this loop:

```
<% @checks.each do |check| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check.name %></td>
    <td><%= check.type.name %></td>
    <td><%= check.department.name %></td>
    <td><%= check.due_by %></td>
    <td><span class="label label-success"><%= check.state.name %></span></td>


    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_check_path(check) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', check, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

and dependant on what `check.sate.name` equals, i need it to have a different class,
for example if it equals `complete`, it has the class `"label label-success"` and if it is `incomplete` it has `"label label-danger"` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what helper methods are for. Change

```
<td><span class="label label-success"><%= check.state.name %></span></td>
```

to something like

```
<td><span class="label label-<%= state_label(check.state.name) %>"><%= check.state.name %></span></td>
```

and then define a `state_label` inside your `app/helpers/check_helper.rb`

```
def state_label(state)
  case state
    when "complete"
      "success"
    when "incomplete"
      "danger"
    else
      "some-default-state"
end
```

I much prefer the decorator/presenter pattern over the implementation of helpers like this. An excellent gem is https://github.com/drapergem/draper Given some `State` you could add a `label_class` method to the `StateDecorator` allowing you to do something like this with a decorated `Check`

```
<td><span class="label label-<%= check.state.label_class %>"><%= check.state.name %></span></td>
```

That `label_class` might look like this

```
def label_class
  case model.state
    when "complete"
      "success"
    when "incomplete"
      "danger"
    else
      "some-default-state"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small helper, e.g.:

```
def check_state_label(state_name)
  label_class = case state_name
                when "complete"
                  "label label-success"
                when "incomplete"
                  "label label-danger"
                else
                  "label"
                end
  content_tag :span, state_name, class: label_class
end
```

And call it this way:

```
<td><%= check_state_label(check.state.name) %></td>
```